# Cannot edit Experience and Education in Careers

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I just joined Careers 2.0 and wanted to complete my profile, yet I am somehow not able to edit the `Experience` and `Education` sections.

When I click the navigation on the top right or the link in the "Completeness report" it will direct me to the according hashed URL (`http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/999999#add-experience` for example), but somehow there's nothing for me to edit.

Everything else worked the way it should. I am using Chrome 20, but the problem also persists when using FF. Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug or some kind of restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug and should be resolved. Try it again?

Comment: Wow, that's fast! Working perfectly now, thanks so much!